# Reactjs & Nodejs App hosting in Firebase issue

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a simple testing project with NodeJS and ReactJS

```
.
├── server
└── web
```

- Server - Is for nodejs
- Web - Is for Reactjs

I know how to host a single react project.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 'server' is an Express application, you can initialize [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) in the same directory and use a `onRequest()` function. You just need to pass the Express app instance in it and you won't have to refactor much of your code. Try running `firebase init` and initialise Cloud functions and Firebase hosting if you haven't already. If the CLI asks for a directory name for hosting, then enter `build` (the directory created when you build your React app)

Your directory structure should look something like this now:

```
app_name/
├─ build/ (React build)
├─ functions/ (created by Firebase CLI for Functions)
│  ├─ index.js
├─ web/ (React app)
```

Then move the contents of "server" in function and pass the Express app instance in `index.js` as shown below:

```
const app = express(); 
// ... routers

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Then make sure all the directory names are updated in `firebase.json` file. It should look this:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build",
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now you can deploy both the service by:

```
firebase deploy --only functions,hosting
```

You must update the API URL in your web app with the Cloud Function's URL. It should be shown in the CLI once you deploy it.